# Unable to get values of keys with space - c#

Tags: c#, azure-cosmosdb

I am querying through documentdb collections which is a dynamic list

```
 var docs = client.CreateDocumentQuery(collection.SelfLink, query, queryOptions); //dynamic List

 docs[0] = {{  "template": "73",  "template with origin": "Test -template1" }}
 docs[1] = {{  "template": "74",  "template with origin": "Test -template2" }}
 docs[2] = {{  "template": "75",  "template with origin": "Test -template3" }}


 for (var i = 0; i < docs.Count; i++)
 {
     var template = docs[i].template; //able to get value
     var tempOfOrigin  = docs[i].GetType().GetProperty("template with origin").GetValue(docs[i], null); //unable to get value
 }
```

Unable to get values of keys with spaces.

Comment: How do you define that property `template with origin` I hope you are not suppose to create a property with spaces

Comment: @un-lucky - Its string

Comment: I'm quite sure that that property name should be a valid C# name (ie, no spaces). Not sure how that would map in Cosmos/JSon. Can you write a [mcve] ?

Comment: what is the return type of `CreateDocumentQuery`

Comment: C# doesn't allow names with spaces. Other languages do. Use `GetProperties` to retrieve all properties and find out how they are named.

Comment: @un-lucky - Its dynamic list

Comment: The Db may support columns or attributes with spaces but C# doesn't for properties.  I'm guessing: `tempOfOrigin  = docs[i]["template with origin"];`

Comment: @Henk - I tried it. But its not working

Comment: Use the debugger. I find the double `{{` `}}` a little confusing, so just find out how your object looks at runtime.

Comment: Why not just camel case it?

Answer (score 0):

> The [Type.GetProperty](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getproperty(v=vs.110).aspx) Method Gets a specific property of the
> current Type. And the overloaded method [`Type.GetProperty Method(String)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kz0a8sxy(v=vs.110).aspx) Searches for the public property with the specified
> name.

And you are not suppose to create a property with spaces[compiler doesn't allow], So you have to try some other methods to access the required values